# Nome composto no modelo não gera plural no nome da tabela

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Gostaria de fazer uma pergunta dando prosseguimento a este post:
[Como programar em português no Ruby on Rails?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/19512/como-programar-em-portugu%C3%AAs-no-ruby-on-rails/184323#184323)

Comecei a estudar rails tem pouco tempo e estou passando por um problema com a pluralização. Quando crio o modelo ProdutoCategoria, ele gera uma migration com o comando create table produto_categoria. Deveria vir produto_categorias não? Se sim, como faço para corrigir isso? Única alteração que fiz foi no infletions.rb:

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect|
  inflect.irregular 'produtocategoria', 'produtocategorias'  
end
```

Mas não resolveu o problema. Podem me ajudar?

Comment: Por experiência própria, eu vou lhe recomendar: não programe com rails em português, você basicamente estará lutando contra o framework só para fazer ele funcionar corretamente, você vai perder muito tempo corrigindo problemas do framework para ser compativel com português e perder toda a questão da agilidade que você ganharia com o rails. Estou falando por experiência própria, já tentei e é simples sofrível as coisas funcionaram (principalmente porque português é uma lingua muito mais complicada para pluralizar palavras do que inglês).

Comment: E você não precisa ser fluente em inglês para escrever código em inglês, com bom senso e usando direito o google você pode escrever um código em inglês com poucas gafes, bom senso dita tudo. Eu mesmo escrevo código em rails em inglês e não sou fluente.

Comment: Entendi Gabriel. Eu realmente estou perdendo tempo tentando descobrir essas coisas. Mas eu achava que era fácil de resolver, eu que não sabia ainda como. Mas pelo jeito desenvolver é o ideal mesmo. Você é a segunda pessoa que eu vejo falar isso aqui no forum. Vou tentar adaptar meu código pro inglês. O nome das colunas das tabelas do banco também precisam ficar em inglês? Não sei se tem alguma pluralização envolvida neste caso.

Comment: Pelo que lembro o i18n poderá ter problemas com os campos, não tenho certeza. Mas como eu disse, faça em inglês, faça "TUDO" em inglês se possível, além de ser o ideal para abrir a sua API para o mundo exterior, você não vai sofrer mais com problemas como o desta pergunta. Hoje no sistema que trabalho só existe um modelo que está escrito em português, que se chama "Nfe", mas que o rails pluralizou para "Nfes", então não tivemos problemas, mas foi o único caso avaliamos e valia deixar o termo em português e não em inglês.

Comment: Mas esse é um caso bem específico, porque o sistema já tem outros modelos que correspondem com "Fatura" em inglês, então por isso não se pode traduzir esse termo "Nfe (Nota fiscal)" para algo como "Invoice", "Receipt", "TaxInvoice", "TaxReceipt"... só que repito, esse é um caso bem específico, em todos os outros sistemas em rails que eu mexi/olhei, não houve necessidade de um termo em português.

Comment: E quanto às mensagens de erro. Aquelas mensagens padrões do rails com letras vermelhas e tal. Nem isso costuma-se traduzir?

Comment: Somente a codificação fica em inglês, mas o retorno para o cliente deveria possuir um suporte para português, mas nesse caso basto você usar o i18n para traduzir os problemas que acontecerem na API.